# TypeStyle how to pass mixins to nested elements

Tags: javascript, typestyle

I want to include a mixin within a nested element in TypeStyle.

The mixin is working great, on the main / root element, but not on a nested element.

```
export const fontSize = (value: number) => {
    const valueStr = value + 'px';
    return {
        fontSize: valueStr
    }
};

export const warning = style(
    fontSize(15), {
        $nest: {
            '& span': ( fontSize(12), {
              backgroundColor: 'yellow'
            })
        }
    });


<div className={warning}>
    This text is formatted correctly
    <span>this text is not</span>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if it's even possible to pass mixins to a nested element. I can give the `span` element an extra class, but that would be more code.

Comment: changed it, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If the element is nested, you obviously want to go for the nested selector `>`, the `&` selector could for instance be used for `:hover`:

```
// fontSize function given by author
const fontSize = (value: number) => {
    const valueStr = value + 'px';
    return {
        fontSize: valueStr
    }
};

// cleaner definition of fontSize function
const fontSizeFunc = (value: number) => ({ fontSize: `${value} px` });

// correct styling object using fontSize function
export const warning = {
  ...fontSize(15),
  $nest: {
    ">": {
      span: {
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        ...fontSize(12),
      },
    },
  },
});

// correct styling object not using fontSize function
export const warning = {
  fontSize: 15,
  $nest: {
    ">": {
      span: {
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        fontSize: 12,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**EDIT:** Added usage of `fontSize` function which returns an object, thus requiring the `spread` operator to yield a correct JS object.

Comment: Hey duschsocke, thank you for your comment. You are right, thanks for the hint, but the fontSize still don't work on the `<span>` element.

Comment: I was not sure about your `fontSize` usage, I guess you meant to use the input value as the fonzsize? If so, check my edited answer.

Comment: Please check the example above, i've created a `const font Size`, you can pass a value to it, it's very basic and makes little sense, it's just an example.

`fontSize(15)`

should be replaced with

`fontSize: '15px'`

and it is.. but not on the nested span element.

Here is an example of how it's working:
[link](https://egghead.io/lessons/css-reusable-styles-using-typestyle-mixins)

Comment: I see! Since your function returns an object and you do not want that object to be nested inside your style, you have to use the spread operator (or `Object.assign(...)`) to merge your style object with the fontsize object. See my (once again) edited answer.

If this is what you were looking for it would be stellar if you marked my answer as "the answer". Thank you!

Comment: Sorry.. still don't work.
is not working:
`'&& span': {
...fontSizeFunc(3)
}
`
is working:
 `'&& span': {
    fontSize: '3px'
 }`

i guess its not possible in typestyle :-) i think you can only pass it to the style object itself